# Host git-backed DocuWiki on Azure Web Sites

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, dokuwiki

I have published a [DocuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) instance on an Azure Web Site with no trouble, following instructions [here](https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:azurewebsites).

I want to set it up so that *content changes by my users* (i.e. independent from configuration changes to the site by my admins) will result in commits to a git repository. The [gitbacked plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:gitbacked) seems to do exactly what I want. However, on its installation page it mentions:

> Note that this plugin only works if you have a git executable
>   available at /usr/bin/git so it requires modifications to the Git
>   wrapper script when you run a chrooted server or don't use linux.

I am not the most seasoned Azure Web Sites administrator, although I understand I am basically running on some form of Shared IIS. Has anyone out there gone through this scenario before and knows what I have to do? I imagine the components of this solution include at least the following after installing the gitbacked plugin:

1. Set up my pages, media, and metadata directories to live outside of the main data directory in the DocuWiki structure as recommended by the [gitbacked documentation](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:gitbacked).
2. Add git executable to the site with adequate permissions to manage the content, or modify the gitbacked wrapper script to use the git executable that Azure Websites can use to manage deployment for the entire site.

Thanks in advance for help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is already installed on all Azure Websites, so it'll probably be easier for you to just modify the wrapper script

Comment: I agree... but is it in the environment or a specific path I need to configure the wrapper script to use in order to access it? Will there be directory permission issues?

Comment: Yes, it's in a specific path.  You can go to your website's Kudu Console  (available at https://<yoursite>.scm.azurewebsites.net) and simply type in "where git" to see that it's located at D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe, and can be invoked by any process running on your site